# Keep running SQL stored procedure after closing C# Console Application

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have written a simple C# console application that calls a SQL stored procedure to update some data in a SQL database.

The issue I have currently is that the process can take up to 10 minutes on the SQL Server and when some users just close the app the SQL also stops. How can I ensure the process completes on the database even if the users close the app while waiting for it to complete?

Comment: You can separate App from DB. You can queue your command using MSMQ, etc and let the queue process your SQL commands against DB. This way you have App and SQL disconnected and even after closing your App, it will not affect DB transaction.

Comment: You could also create a SQL Agent job that can do the work and be started from your application.

Comment: I can see that both MSMQ and SQL Agent job are valid options but it will not work in my case. I can not ensure MSMQ is installed nor can I add jobs in SQL server. I was hoping for a C# option where I can control the environment. Maybe something like async ....?